# ggcyto - using fill according to variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use ggcyto on a dataframe of cells, in addition to preforming gating on it.
I wish to color the dots in the plot (created by geom_point) according to a third variable that is in the dataframe. is that possible?
when attempting to use "fill = x" it just returns an error that there is no such variable "X" no matter what I try doing..
here is the original code used for the plot:

```
library(ggcyto)
library(flowCore)
library(ncdfFlow)
library(flowAssist)

# Convert the matrix into a flowFrame object
ff <- DFtoFF(DATA[c("Median.var1", "Median.var2", "Median.var3")])

# Create a flowSet object from the flowFrame
fs <- flowSet(ff)


# Create a plot using ggcyto
p <- ggcyto(fs, aes(x = Median.var1, y = Median.var2)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Median.var3)) +
  labs(x = "Median Intensity - var1", 
       y = "Median intenisty - var2") +
  ggtitle("var1 vs var2- Median")
```

I expected a plot for coloring different variables, but instead get the following error message:

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
i Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'Median.var3' not found
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to make this error reproducible? Have you tried, `aes(x = Median.var1, y = Median.var2, fill = Median.var3)`?